# Programmatically retrieve the updated file from server

Tags: iphone, ios, webserver

I have a file(XYZ.XXX) kept on my webserver. I have an iPhone client where user can input some data. After entering the data, use will click on Submit button. I send these string data to the server. Server has a component to append this data to that file (XYZ.XXX). And Server has to send back that updated file to my iPhone app. What would be the best approach to program this?
I have a client app ready without communication piece. I am thinking to use http POST method to send the data as request.

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I need to create a server component to receive this data and append with that file(XYZ.XXX). But how can the iPhone app get that updated file from server with the same request? Do my iPhone app has to request one more time to get the updated file? (or) With the first request itself, can it receive the updated file from the response itself?

Please advise and provide your input.

Comment: Ok. Whatever it is, my response is a xyz.config file, so when i get response as .config file, it should be able to automatically download and ask for profile installation like how we download a .config file manually sync via USB cable. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually want to avoid a synchronous request on the main thread as that will cause the app to appear to be locked up to the user. Have a look at apple's documentation on creating an NSURLConnection and using the delegate methods.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE

Comment: Thank you very much. My question intend to ask this is, response is like a file, can i download the file directly in the response? "connectionDidFinishLoading" gives the complete response, but this file gets in the response as a .config file and has to install on the device. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use NSFileManager to save the file onto the device. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Could you please explain a little more? Why should i save it in disk? Eventhough if i save it on the device, can i download and install the .config file?

Comment: "Installing the file" only has meaning with in the context of your application, you can process the file however you need to. Syncing via USB will place the files in your default documents directory for your bundle, you can achieve the same effect by saving the file with NSFileManager

Comment: Hi, Ok. I tried to copy .config file into the Documents directory. But, its just copying the file into the directory, that's all. It doesn't do auto installation of config profile, like how Safari downloading such files.